# Hover Issue - Show Image On Hover

Tags: html, css

novice here.

The goal is to show an image on hover that contains text. I got technically what I wanted, when I hover over the 'test' container the image shows. But when I hover over the 'text' area it doesn't show. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <img class="testimg" src="images/feat-img2.jpg">
    <p class="test-text">This is a caption text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #111111;
}
.test img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.test:hover, .test img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.testimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.test-text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[HOVERED OVER TEXT & ORIGINAL STATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B0yA.jpg)

[HOVERED OVER CONTAINER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uAZ1.jpg)

Comment: Change your hover CSS rule from `.test:hover, .test img:hover` to `.test:hover img`

Comment: Thank you so much jla - I knew it would be something in the wrong place. Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 2):

Add this attribute to your test-text class

```
pointer-events: none;
```